# QImage::setPixel does not look the same depending of the OS

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qimage

I'm using the method QImage::setPixel() to draw some lines on a QImage.
For example, to create a horizontal line, I'm doing this :

```
for(int i = x1; i <= x2; i++)
{
    this->mazeImage->setPixel(i, y1, qRgb(0,0,0));
}
```

This is an exemple of how it looks on my PC (Windows 10):
[image: example of lines on Windows]
**As you can see, some lines looks wider than others.**

And the same example on a other PC (Linux):
[image: example of lines on Linux]
**As you can see, the lines are perfect.**

So how can I handle that and get some perfect lines also on Windows ?

Comment: Most probably you are displaying image as scaled (not 1:1 with screen resolution) and you see scaling artifacts. After all for some reason size of this pictures is different.

Comment: Also note that `QImage` is a `QPaitDevice` so you can use `QPainter` to draw on it. You do not have to draw line pixel by pixel.

Comment: Probably due to rounding in High-DPI display or when your display zoom is not 100 % or 200 %. Check so called "device-pixel-ratio". See also https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html but beware that some things changed from Qt5 to Qt6. So if you are planning to upgarde to Qt6 soon, you probably should do it before solving this issue.